# Reusable elements in main CakePHP layout

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, view, element

I would like to pull in different Views in my default layout.

'default.ctp' is my main layout template and this is currently only pulling in content from 'view/posts/index.ctp', however, I'd also like to include my add news form ('view/posts/add.ctp') in this template.

Is this easy to achieve?

I looked at the manual about 'elements' but it didn't seem to help.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render on a page for one action result of another action, Object::requestAction() can halp you.

In place in view (view/posts/index.ctp), where you want to display other view (view/posts/add.ctp), put this cpode:

```
echo $this->requestAction('/posts/add', array('return'));
```

[More about requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html?highlight=requestaction#Controller%3a%3arequestAction)

In case if you want only render other templete - View::render() for you.
This method render a templete only without execution action and don't work correct in same situations (eg. where used paginator).

Code:

```
echo $this->render('/Posts/add', false);
```

'/Posts/add' - for CakePHP 2, for 1.3 - '/posts/add'

Comment: Thanks for the help here :-) I added `
<?php echo $this->requestAction('/posts/add', array('return')); ?>` to my 'index.ctp' and with a bit of jiggery pokery, it did the trick :) Thanks again for taking the time to help out here. Have a good day!!